# Zigbee Network in API mode

Tags: xbee, zigbee

Can anyone tell me how I can see all XBee modules linked in my Pan ID? I want to send from Coordinator the command and receive the number, and Network ID, of all XBee modules linked in same Pan ID.

My modules are all Series 2.

Comment: My xbees modules are Series 2

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command for this is `ATND`.

Just send the packet `0x7E 0x00 0x06 0x08 0x01 0x41 0x54 0x4E 0x44 0xCF` to the coordinator.